# My code of "load more posts" on wordpress misses some pages. What's wrong with it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a problem with the "load more posts" code. I don't know what it is, and can't use the chrome debug because it's with ajax.

Every time I scroll to the bottom of the page, the function activates and load the next page to the current page. it jumps over pages 6, 8, 11, 13, 16... didn't check more pages. 
When I refresh and scroll again, it jumps over other random pages.

this is the code of the "pbd-ajax-load-posts" plugin I use. I customized it to my needs:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // The number of the next page to load (/page/x/).
    var pageNum = parseInt(pbd_alp.startPage);

    // The maximum number of pages the current query can return.
    var max = parseInt(pbd_alp.maxPages);

    // The link of the next page of posts.
    var nextLink = pbd_alp.nextLink;

    //what page am I on? 
    var whatPage = pbd_alp.theTitle;
    //console.log(whatPage);

    /**
     * Replace the traditional navigation with our own,
     * but only if there is at least one page of new posts to load.
     */
    if(pageNum <= max) {
        // Insert the "More Posts" link.
        $('#content')
            .append('<div class="pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +'"  ></div>')
            .append('<p id="pbd-alp-load-posts"><a href="#" id="loadmoreLink" onclick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'Click\', \'LoadMore\', \''+ whatPage +'\']);">Load More Posts</a></p>');

        // Remove the traditional navigation.
        $('.navigation').remove();
    }


    /**
     * Load new posts when the link is clicked.
     */
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50) {


            // Are there more posts to load?
            if(pageNum <= max) {
                                console.log(max);

                // Show that we're working.
                $('#loadmoreLink').text('Loading posts...');

                $('.pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum).load(nextLink + ' .post',
                    function() {
                        // Update page number and nextLink.
                        console.log(pageNum);
                        pageNum++;
                        console.log(pageNum);
                        nextLink = 'http://www.example.com.br/page/' + pageNum;
                        console.log(nextLink);

                        // Add a new placeholder, for when user clicks again.
                        $('#pbd-alp-load-posts')
                            .before('<div class="pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +'"></div>');
                        console.log("---------------------");
                        // Update the button message.
                        if(pageNum <= max) {
                            $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').text('Load More Posts');
                        } else {
                            $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').text('No more posts to load.');
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    });

});
```

The problematic part begins in the code here:

> ```
>   /**
>    * Load new posts when the link is clicked.
>    */
> ```

(the second time I scrolled, it loaded page 2, and the console.log shows that it loaded page 3,4 and 5 with page 2 without showing them.) This is my console.log output:

```
The number of the next page to load: 1 (always begins with 1 so it could get page 2) 
The number of the next page to load after increment: 2 
The link of the next page of posts: http://www.example.com.br/page/2 
--------END AJAX------------- 
The number of the next page to load: 2 
The number of the next page to load after increment: 3 
The link of the next page of posts: http://www.example.com.br/page/3 
--------END AJAX------------- 
The number of the next page to load: 3 
The number of the next page to load after increment: 4 
The link of the next page of posts: http://www.example.com.br/page/4 
--------END AJAX-------------
```

What might be the problem? because everything should work properly, I went over the code a million times!

Comment: First of all "can't use the chrome debug because it's with ajax." Use the Network panel. You can inspect each ajax request, its content and the associated response. Also, you should deactivate scrolling while your loading new posts, to prevent user from scrolling up and down and reactivate the loading process. To finish, your console prints are unreadable.

Comment: The network panel doesn't show the pages that should load and skips them. doesn't give me any perception of what the problem can be except the thing that it doesn't load for an unknown reason. 

stopping loading while scrolling might be a good idea in general. It would be nice if you will help me out with this.. :) 


I rewrote the console.log. I hope it's more understandable.

Comment: @TCHdvlp I made a few test, I think It's really because something with the scrolling. Do you have any idea how to fix this, or do you recommend to open a new post specifically for this issue?

Comment: I think your title is good, prevent scrolling could be a good practice in "load more posts" scenarios. If you want to keep a good UI, you should'nt prevent scrolling, user may find this uncomfortable and may not understand why. You can use a flag (basically, a boolean variable) to know if a loading has started yet. `var isLoading = false; $(window).scroll(function() { if(scrollTop()... && !isLoading) { isLoading=true; do your stuff; loading finished=> isLoading = false; }});`

Comment: `var canRun = true;
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if( ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50 ) && (canRun==true) ) {
   canRun = false;

                      //do stuff 

                       canRun = true;
             }
});
`

Am I doing sonthing wrong because it's still not working.

Comment: I took the scroller and moved it up and down and got a lot of outputs from the console.logs inside.

Comment: also tried: 

`var canRun = true;
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if (canRun==true){
   if( ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50 )) {
   canRun = false; `

isn't working

Comment: let's continue in the http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57496/load-more-posts. Hope you can join

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. :( 

walid.doch@gmail.com gtalk

Comment: I don't see your ajax calls in your code. Where did they gone ?